# How perform task with dependencies and scheduling

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, scheduled-tasks, database-backups

I have a list of task that must be scheduled, like with cron. This is for backups on sql server.

The database will execute FULL, DIFF, LOGS backups in several combinations.

So:

- FULL each day at 8:00am
- DIFF each hour
- LOG each 10 minutes

However, I have this problems:

- If the server wake up at 8:15am, the FULL task is not executed.
- If the FULL fail, then not make sense to execute DIFF & LOG
- If server wake up 8:15am at saturday, LOG start 8:20 to launch, then for full must wait for next Monday.
- If LOG take too much (is not finished at 9:01am) so DIFF start when LOG is yet not complete. I don't wanna that!

I do this with quartz.net, but that is tangential -I'm open to change lib, remove it, etc.-. So my main objective is reliability in the sequence/execution of task.

In sequential code, this is very easy to do:

- DO_FULL THEN
- DO_DIFF THEN
- DO_LOG

However, with a scheduler this get impossible (at least with quartz).

THe problem is the management of time. When the task is marked to start each hour, must be more a hint than a hard rule, because the previous one could be not finished. Also, do the FULL is a requirement to start the cycle.

I wonder that algorithm must be applied here.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution is to write a windows service (which, by design, runs continuously).

1. Windows Service wakes up one of its threads (T0) 8:00.
2. T0 performs necessary validations and raises alarm and aborts if they fail, else spawns full backup thread T1.
3. T1 will only be executed when all validations are good, so just proceed with backup.
4. If T1 completes successfully, service wakes up its diff thread (T2) and log thread (T3).
5. T2 and T3 check for last successful run of T1. If T1 had failed, T2 and T3 abort too.
6. T2 executes every hour, performs diff and sleeps.
7. T3 executes every 15mins. It must check if T2 is running, if yes, then sleep again (for x seconds) and try again. If T2 is not running T3, should perform its duties.
8. At some predetermined time at the end of day, all threads should be reset or aborted, if required.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to keep track of the tasks that are executed. For example, for DIFF to run, FULL must be executed first. To achieve this, start the task and set the status of FULL to false. When the FULL completes its work, set the status to true. When the time is there for the DIFF to run, it checks if the FULL is ready (based on true or false value that FULL generates). If it is not, then the DIFF just waits until the FULL sends a signal that it has completed its work (true). The same is true for LOG to run. This is a simple way of achieving the sequential behavior.